# Change font for £ after page loaded

Tags: jquery, cufon

I have a situation where the font in a H3 element is being replace by Cufon with a font that does not have a pound L (£).

As a quick fix I want to replace any £ in H3 element with a different font AFTER cufon has done it's thing.

I think jQuery can do this. I guess it will have to replace the £ with a span tag which calls a different font?

Comment: Yup. That sounds about right. What's the question exactly or are we just here for moral support? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous answer changes font for whole element, this does just the one character.

```
$('h3').each(function() {$(this).html($(this).html().replace('&pound;','<span font="your font">&pound;</span>'));});
```

Comment: I added an extra ) after around the .replace(...) and this works fine. Unfortunately the £ character is not in the target string as it is not in the font used by cufon (that was dumb of me). Therefore this solution will only work if I replace the £ with something else before cufon is called, then replace it back afterwards, changing the font to something that does have the £ character.

Answer (score 1):

This checks all `h3` elements with the "oldFont" class for occurrences of the "£" character and wraps them all in a `span` with a class of "newFont":

```
$("h3.oldFont").each(function() {
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/£/g, "<span class='newFont'>£</span>")); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h3:contains('£')").css('font-face','Arial');

});
```

Comment: I think he wants to replace *just* the £ with a different font and not the whole h3 element. So the innerHTML (`.html()`) would need to be replaced with `<span class="pound">£</span>`.